# Spring LogOut function Not logging out

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to write a logout function that returns the user to the main page ("/") but when I press the button it doesn't do anything. I have been following tutorials but they all seem to have the same issue that it isn't working for me.

**Security Config code**

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin")
        .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin")
        .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout().logoutUrl("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        ;
        return;
}
```

**Controller**

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null){
        new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
    }
    return "redirect:/login?logout";
}
```

**And finally the JSP Logout is stored**

```html
<body>
    <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Any help would be massively appreciated. And any other tips as it's my first post here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

logout() configuration:

```
.logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout.done")
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
```

Or programmatically in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
HttpSession session= request.getSession(false);
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
     session= request.getSession(false);
    if(session != null) {
        session.invalidate();
    }
    for(Cookie cookie : request.getCookies()) {
        cookie.setMaxAge(0);
    }

return "logout";
```

Choose one of this ways, you should not add .logout() config if you've created custom route

On jsp:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately its still not working. I have added the code into the security config.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm afraid its still not working, I've added the new controller code to my main controller but alas it is still not working. Could it be due to anything in the JSP?

Comment: @JeffereyJohnSmith try to type {site}/logout from browser, not from jsp and check :1) whether logout performed 2) whether you can to catch your logout method with a breakpoint in debug mode. And choose only one of the approaches described. You shouldn't provide both logout config and controller method together.

Comment: Okay, if I call logout from url it does indeed log me out, what do I need to do so I can have a button or a link to do this for me?

Comment: @JeffereyJohnSmith <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}">Logout</a>

Answer (score 0):

Mofify your SecurityConfig like so:

```
.and()
.logout()
.logoutUrl("/logout")
.logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
.permitAll()
```